# Movement code of pygame sprites not working correctly

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to create a Space Invaders clone using Pygame as part of a class project. I have some issues with getting the aliens to move correctly.

The aliens should reach a boundary, move down the screen, and their direction variable should change (1 for right, 2 for left). If the direction variable is right, they'll move right along the screen and vice versa for moving left, until they reach another boundary and move down the screen again, in a continuous loop.

I had this working with a single instance of the Alien class, but when trying to integrate into a group setting it doesn't seem to work at all...

To try and help I added a "flag" variable since I think the issue is maybe with the fact that all the aliens are basing their movement off of the movement of the first alien to hit the "wall", but I'm not sure it's doing anything to help anymore than the direction variable...

(please excuse the mess and lack of competent commentary!)

```
import pygame
import sys

class Fighter(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self,life):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        fighterImage = pygame.image.load("..\Graphics\FighterSprite.png").convert_alpha() #convert alpha makes imgs transparent
        self.image = pygame.Surface([32,32])
        self.image.set_colorkey(black) # makes surfaces transparent
        self.image.blit(fighterImage, (0,0))
        self.life = 3
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 300
        self.rect.y = 700

    def move_ship(self, direction, pixels):
        if direction == 1 and self.rect.x <=560:
            self.rect.x += pixels
        if direction == 2 and self.rect.x >=10:
            self.rect.x -= pixels

class Alien(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self,alive,x):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface([32,32])
        self.image.set_colorkey(black)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = 400 #about midway down screen for testing purposes
        alienSprite = pygame.image.load("..\Grpahics\EnemyAlien1Static.png")
        self.image.blit(alienSprite, (0,0))
        self.alive = True

    def update(self,directional,flag):
        if self.rect.x >= 560:
            directonal = 2 #sets the direction to "left"
            flag = "LEFT" #sets the flag to "left" so all other aliens know
            self.rect.y = self.rect.y+10 #moves alien down the screen
        elif self.rect.x <= 10:
            directional = 1 #sets the direction to "right"
            flag = "RIGHT" #sets the flag to "right" so all other aliens know
            self.rect.y = self.rect.y+10
        if directional == 1 or flag == "RIGHT":
            self.rect.x += 1 #aliens move to the right
        else:
            self.rect.x -= 1 #aliens move to the left
        return directional, flag #updates direction of aliens for each loop

    def kill(self):
        self.alive = False

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([600,800])
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")
background_image = pygame.image.load("..\Graphics\spaceinvbackground.png")
background_image = pygame.transform.scale(background_image, (600,800))
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
green = (122,240,112)

bullets = []
bulletgraphic = pygame.image.load("..\Graphics\FighterBullet.png")
bulletgraphic = pygame.transform.scale(bulletgraphic, (32,32))

direction = 0
directional = 1 #sets initial direction to right
flag = "RIGHT" #sets initial flag to right

score = 0

fighter_pilot = Fighter(True)
player = pygame.sprite.Group()
player.add(fighter_pilot)
alien = Alien(True,1,300)
alien1 = Alien(True,1,350)
alien2 = Alien(True,1,400)
alien3 = Alien(True,1,450)
alien4 = Alien(True,1,500)
alien5 = Alien(True,1,550)
aliens = pygame.sprite.Group() #this is the group in which all the alien enemies are in
aliens.add(alien,alien1,alien2,alien3,alien4,alien5)

while done == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if len(aliens) == 0: 
            done = True 
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                direction = 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                direction = 2
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                bullets.append([(fighter_pilot.rect.x+13), fighter_pilot.rect.y]) #x value is roughly centre of ship, y value is same as ship
                fired = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a: # only works on key up for left/right arrows & A/D keys
                direction = 0

    fighter_pilot.move_ship(direction, 5)

    directional = aliens.update(directional, flag) #this line updates the aliens direction with every time the program loops

    for b in range(len(bullets)):
        bullets[b][1]-=10
        if fired == True:
            if alien.rect.x >= (fighter_pilot.rect.x+13)-22 and alien.rect.x <= (fighter_pilot.rect.x+13)+22 and alien.alive == True:
                if alien.rect.y == bullets[b][1]:
                    aliens.remove(alien)
                    alien.kill()
                    bullets.pop()
                    score = score + 100
            if alien1.rect.x >= (fighter_pilot.rect.x+13)-22 and alien1.rect.x <= (fighter_pilot.rect.x+13)+22 and alien1.alive == True:
                if alien1.rect.y == bullets[b][1]:
                    aliens.remove(alien1)
                    alien1.kill()
                    bullets.pop()
                    score = score + 100
            if alien2.rect.x >= (fighter_pilot.rect.x+13)-22 and alien2.rect.x <= (fighter_pilot.rect.x+13)+22 and alien2.alive == True:
                if alien2.rect.y == bullets[b][1]:
                    aliens.remove(alien2)
                    alien2.kill()
                    bullets.pop()
                    score = score + 100
            if alien3.rect.x >= (fighter_pilot.rect.x+13)-22 and alien3.rect.x <= (fighter_pilot.rect.x+13)+22 and alien3.alive == True:
                if alien3.rect.y == bullets[b][1]:
                    aliens.remove(alien3)
                    alien3.kill()
                    bullets.pop()
                    score = score + 100
            if alien4.rect.x >= (fighter_pilot.rect.x+13)-22 and alien4.rect.x <= (fighter_pilot.rect.x+13)+22 and alien4.alive == True:
                if alien4.rect.y == bullets[b][1]:
                    aliens.remove(alien4)
                    alien4.kill()
                    bullets.pop()
                    score = score + 100
            if alien5.rect.x >= (fighter_pilot.rect.x+13)-22 and alien5.rect.x <= (fighter_pilot.rect.x+13)+22 and alien5.alive == True:
                if alien5.rect.y == bullets[b][1]:
                    aliens.remove(alien5)
                    alien5.kill()
                    bullets.pop()
                    score = score + 100

    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet[0]<0:
            bullets.pop()

    screen.blit(background_image, (0,0))
    for bullet in bullets:
        screen.blit(bulletgraphic, pygame.Rect(bullet[0], bullet[1], 0, 0))
    aliens.draw(screen)
    player.draw(screen)
    scoreImg = font.render(str(score),1,green)
    screen.blit(scoreImg, (10,10))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

I really cannot figure out why this isn't working - it does however work if you use the update function on one alien?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `-1` for left and `1` for right will make so many things much less confusing...

Comment: _"please excuse the mess"_ On the contrary, please _edit the mess_ before posting. Help us help you by making your question clear. Remember that we have never seen your program before and have absolutely no idea what you're talking about unless you explain it. I would [suggest having a friend read over your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337330/603977) before you post and editing it in response to feedback.

Comment: I recommend using Enumerated types for your directions and declaring them explicitly throughout (name not by value). from enum import Enum

Should make it more readable too (if indeed another edit will be supplied)

Comment: I cannot execute the game without the images. Either remove the code that uses images and just color in the `Rect`s or post a link to the images.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have revised and fixed your code. The main issue that I found was that the code had some logical errors and unnecessary variables that just bloated the code and made it harder to understand.

**Main issues:**

- `flag` variable is not needed.
- Passing a `directional` variable into the `update` method is not needed and may have been causing bugs.
- `directional` should really be an object field instead of a variable outside the class. It makes more sense that this variable belongs to every individual alien doesn't it.
- The initial `y` value that was passed to the `Alien` constructor was less than 10 causing the `Alien`s to free fall before their x value was greater than 10.
- An object `font` was used in the program but was not initialized.

The `flag` variable is not needed because every `Alien` moves in sync with the other. So therefore if one `Alien` knows that it has to change direction, they all do.

Similarly, passing these two global variables into the `update` method is really not the best way of doing it and does not make much object-oriented sense.

In regards to making the `directional` variable global. This is just not a good design decision and it makes more object-oriented sense to have it part of each of the individual `Alien` object.

**Other differences with my code:**

- Removed the use of the `font` object.
- Did not render any images and just filled the `Surfaces` with colors instead.
- Removed some other code that is not useful in the context of a post.

I hope that this answer was helpful to you and if you have any further questions please feel free to post a comment below!

**Revised code:**

```
import pygame

class Fighter(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self,life):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.Surface([32,32])
        self.image.set_colorkey(black) # makes surfaces transparent
        self.image.fill((0, 255, 0))

        self.life = 3

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 300
        self.rect.y = 700

    def move_ship(self, direction, pixels):
        if direction == 1 and self.rect.x <=560:
            self.rect.x += pixels
        if direction == 2 and self.rect.x >=10:
            self.rect.x -= pixels

class Alien(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self,alive,x,y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.Surface([32,32])
        self.image.set_colorkey(black)
        self.image.fill((255, 0, 0))

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y #about midway down screen for testing purposes

        self.alive = True
        self.directional = 1

    def update(self):
        if self.rect.x >= 560:
            self.directional = 2
            self.rect.y += 10

        elif self.rect.x <= 10:
            self.directional = 1
            self.rect.y += 10


        if self.directional == 1:
            self.rect.x += 1 #aliens move to the right

        else:
            self.rect.x -= 1 #aliens move to the left

    def kill(self):
        self.alive = False

pygame.init()

window_width = 600
window_height = 800

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([window_width,window_height])

done = False

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
green = (122,240,112)

bullets = []
bulletgraphic = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
bulletgraphic.fill((0, 0, 200))

direction = 0

score = 0

fighter_pilot = Fighter(True)

player = pygame.sprite.Group()
player.add(fighter_pilot)

alien = Alien(True,20,300)
alien1 = Alien(True,20,350)
alien2 = Alien(True,20,400)
alien3 = Alien(True,20,450)
alien4 = Alien(True,20,500)
alien5 = Alien(True,20,550)
aliens = pygame.sprite.Group() #this is the group in which all the alien enemies are in
aliens.add(alien,alien1,alien2,alien3,alien4,alien5)

while done == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if len(aliens) == 0: 
            done = True 
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                direction = 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                direction = 2
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                bullets.append([(fighter_pilot.rect.x+13), fighter_pilot.rect.y]) #x value is roughly centre of ship, y value is same as ship
                fired = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a: # only works on key up for left/right arrows & A/D keys
                direction = 0

    fighter_pilot.move_ship(direction, 5)

    aliens.update() #this line updates the aliens direction with every time the program loops

    for b in range(len(bullets)):
        bullets[b][1]-=10
        if fired == True:
            if alien.rect.x >= (fighter_pilot.rect.x+13)-22 and alien.rect.x <= (fighter_pilot.rect.x+13)+22 and alien.alive == True:
                if alien.rect.y == bullets[b][1]:
                    aliens.remove(alien)
                    alien.kill()
                    bullets.pop()
                    score = score + 100
            if alien1.rect.x >= (fighter_pilot.rect.x+13)-22 and alien1.rect.x <= (fighter_pilot.rect.x+13)+22 and alien1.alive == True:
                if alien1.rect.y == bullets[b][1]:
                    aliens.remove(alien1)
                    alien1.kill()
                    bullets.pop()
                    score = score + 100
            if alien2.rect.x >= (fighter_pilot.rect.x+13)-22 and alien2.rect.x <= (fighter_pilot.rect.x+13)+22 and alien2.alive == True:
                if alien2.rect.y == bullets[b][1]:
                    aliens.remove(alien2)
                    alien2.kill()
                    bullets.pop()
                    score = score + 100
            if alien3.rect.x >= (fighter_pilot.rect.x+13)-22 and alien3.rect.x <= (fighter_pilot.rect.x+13)+22 and alien3.alive == True:
                if alien3.rect.y == bullets[b][1]:
                    aliens.remove(alien3)
                    alien3.kill()
                    bullets.pop()
                    score = score + 100
            if alien4.rect.x >= (fighter_pilot.rect.x+13)-22 and alien4.rect.x <= (fighter_pilot.rect.x+13)+22 and alien4.alive == True:
                if alien4.rect.y == bullets[b][1]:
                    aliens.remove(alien4)
                    alien4.kill()
                    bullets.pop()
                    score = score + 100
            if alien5.rect.x >= (fighter_pilot.rect.x+13)-22 and alien5.rect.x <= (fighter_pilot.rect.x+13)+22 and alien5.alive == True:
                if alien5.rect.y == bullets[b][1]:
                    aliens.remove(alien5)
                    alien5.kill()
                    bullets.pop()
                    score = score + 100

    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet[0]<0:
            bullets.pop()

    screen.fill(black)


    for bullet in bullets:
        screen.blit(bulletgraphic, pygame.Rect(bullet[0], bullet[1], 0, 0))

    aliens.draw(screen)
    player.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Thanks very much!! I definitely should have tidied my code up more before posting (I'm using multiple prototypes to test different elements but some variables are still being used where they don't need to be e.g. font). I still have a lot to learn about Pygame and object orientated programming in general so this has been a big help.

Comment: why are there two downvotes on this answer?

Comment: There was a lot of dissatisfaction with the quality of the OP's code. I think this caused some people to downvote to discourage answering these "low quality" questions.